# How can I fill the tank on my older pickup truck?

Tags: ford, fuel-tank, f-250

I have a 1974 Ford F250 and I have an extremely difficult time filling the tanks at gas stations with the newer rubber boots on the gas nozzles. The physical shape of the older pickup truck gas filler opening is just not designed to work well with the newer gas pump nozzles. I have to pull back the boot with my hand and hold the lever at about 30% of full-speed.

Are there any products that I can use to make filling up easier? The only idea I've got is to buy a large external gas tank and fill up from there.

Here is a photo of the truck in question.

[image: Gas filler]

Comment: I've had luck turning the filling nozzle upside down while filling. This seems to keep it from shutting off prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [these](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/filler-neck-seal) are the correct items, but you could find/make some kind of insert to hold the nozzle in place? I supposed you could also cut the filler neck from a car in the scrap yard and adapt it to your truck, but I imagine you don't want to stray too far from the OEM setup (or if it is even legal to do so).

Comment: How do those work? Do I just use them temporarily while I am filling up?

Comment: @JeremyWhite I'm not sure, I've never seen or used them. Removing it would probably be the safest though maybe not the most practical or cleanest solution. If you could find some way to fasten it in there, perhaps a flange that pinches between the cap and filler neck?.